# How to fit these two classes together?

Tags: javascript, oop, ecmascript-6

This is my first attempt at doing OOP and made a simple Pomodoro timer. https://codepen.io/hyrosian/project/editor/XpjOPR

There was an attempt to seperate the countdown timer from the controls. The countdown timer is working but i'm not sure how to get class Counter and class Controls somehow 'fit' together.

```
const counter = new Counter(DOMnode)
const controls = new Controls()
```

The plan was to set up the eventlisteners and handlers inside `Controls`. We get the values e.g. +5mins for changing the session/break length inside of it. But Controls needs access to the state inside Counter.

```
class Controls extends Time {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.session_btn = document.querySelectorAll('[data-session]')
        this.break_btn = document.querySelectorAll('[data-break]')
    }

    handleBreak(e) {
        console.log(e.target.dataset.break)
    }
    
    handleSession(e) {
        console.log(e.target.dataset.session)
    }
    
    init() {
        this.session_btn.forEach(btn => btn.addEventListener('click', this.handleSession))
        this.break_btn.forEach(btn => btn.addEventListener('click', this.handleBreak))
    }
}
```

What would be the proper way to fit them together?

Answer (score 0):

`Controls` should have a reference to the Counter object, but not the other way around.

`Controls` can access the state by asking for (getTime, getState). If `Controls` needs to subscribe to some event (timer has run out) then `Counter` could emit such an event.

The underlying idea would be that Counter is a completely isolated object and just maintains its own state and timers, but `Controls` is the thing that handles events from the user (and potentially updates the DOM when needed).

This is a pretty common pattern. In this scenario, `Counter` would often be called the model, and `Controls` the Controller.

You should first create the `Counter`, and pass it as a constructor argument to `Controls`

Comment: Cetico, I think the Controller should hold a reference to both the DomNode and the Counter. The Counter (I think) should be your model and nothing else, which means it doesn't really talk to anything else, it just gets talked to. If you want another class to display the timer, then that should be a second 'controller', which means you have 2 controllers and 1 model. Also take a look at the Backbone.js framework which is a super minimal implementation of this idea and you can read the source in an hour.